# handling collisions - array look ups expensive

Tags: java, android, collision-detection

I have a collision detection method in my android program to detect when two balls have collided and to calculate their new velocities. Every ball is stored in an array `Ball[] ballArray`. To handle collisions, I iterate through each ball, take it's center coordinates and calculate a surrounding region. If the center of any other ball lies within this region, then I check the two balls for a collision.

My method is basically as follows

```
public void handleCollisions(){
    int size = ballArray.length;

    for(int i = 0; i < size; i++){
         Ball ball = ballArray[i];
         int centerX = ball.centerX;
         int centerY = ball.centerY;
         int radius = ball.radius;

         //calculate box around ball
         int lowXLimit =  (centerX - radius - largestPossibleRadius);
         int highXLimit =  (centerX + radius + largestPossibleRadius);
         int lowYLimit =  (centerY- radius - largestPossibleRadius);
         int highYLimit =  (centerY+ radius + largestPossibleRadius);

        for(int j = j+1; j < size; j++){
            Ball ball2 = ballArray[j];
            int centerX2 = ball.centerX;
            int centerY2 = ball.centerY;
            int radius2 = ball.radius;

            //if ball2 is inside the possible collision region around ball1
            if (centerX2  > lowXLimit && centerX2 < highXLimit  && centerY2 > lowYLimit && centerY2 < highYLimit) {
                //do calculations to determine new velocities
            } 
}
```

I was getting pretty poor performance from my code and ran a traceview. To my surprise, only around 5% of the execution time in this method is spent doing the collision resolution calculations (quite a number of floating point divisions, multiplications). In fact, around 60-70% of time in this method is simply accessing the balls from the ball array (lines `Ball ball = ballArray[i]` and `Ball ball2 = ballArray[j]`).

I've tried using an `ArrayList` but that is even worse. Is there something I can do to speed up this code? perhaps another data structure? It seems like a really long time to me. Should I try reduce the number of member variables in `Ball`?

Comment: I wonder if it wouldn't be more efficient to declare ball and ball2 outside of the loops and only re-affecting at each iteration

Comment: also, I think linked list may be more efficient to loop through elements

Comment: `ball` and `ball2` are only references to existing Objects - not a slow operation (`new`). The difference to declaring those outside the loop and just updating the reference inside the loop should be close to zero. But try it - it's an interesting question.

Comment: @zapl: not "close to zero", it should be exactly zero. The JIT will hoist loop variables and unroll loops if it will make a performance improvement.

Comment: @SeanReilly This may not be the case for android. Not all devices have a JIT

Comment: @AlanCarson: Dalvik has had a JIT since 2.2 (http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2010/05/dalvik-jit.html). More than that, moving a variable declaration outside of the loop is so trivial that it's almost certainly done at compile time to get a constant size stack frame.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are some points that could be optimized:

You could calculate ball collision with just the radius. Distance between balls = sqrt((x1-x2)^2 + (y1-y2)^2), now if distance between balls < (radius1 + radius2) then they collide.

To calculate that efficiently you should keep distance squared (no sqrt) and compare with (radius1 + radius2)^2. That way might be faster than what you currently do.

If you have n Balls you currently have to do like n^2 comparisons which gets quite a lot for many balls. So that would be a good point to look for optimizations:

There are really advanced "spatial data structures" (google that) that would allow you to compare Balls with less then all Balls (just with balls close enough so it's likely that they collide). The problematic thing with those is that you have to maintain that structure (update it whenever your balls move) which is usually quite a lot of calculations and might end up slower that your approach.

Example: http://www.gamerendering.com/2008/11/17/uniform-grid/
You take a grid with cellsize = the max diameter a ball can have. Whenever you move a ball you update it's position in the grid (that's a quite simple divide by gridwidth). Then you just need to compare a Ball with Balls inside this or directly adjacent cells.

> I've tried using an ArrayList but that is even worse. Is there something I can do to speed up this code? perhaps another data structure? It seems like a really long time to me. Should I try reduce the number of member variables in Ball?

There is pretty much nothing you can do by using different classes/members. Your Ball[] array with public members is the most efficient way to do that. The amount of members of Ball should have no effect on the speed.

Comment: I like the idea of the uniform grid. Although I would still have to access each ball of the array to determine which cell it was in? which seems to be costly. It would cut down on the computation though. Alternatively I could have an ArrayList<Ball> for each cell and hope the garbage collection doesn't get too bad. I think I will try these out, thank you

Comment: If you make it a `LinkedList<Ball>[cellX][cellY]` that indexes all Balls in a cell then you can add / remove them without much GC. But it's probably still slow

Comment: If I have a fixed number of balls. I'm just thinking, what if I had another structure for each cell of the grid. It could contain simply the indexes of the balls that are in the cell. For example, it could store 1,4,7 - meaning ballArray[1], ballArray[4] etc was in the cell. Is there a way I could maintain these lists without leaving memory that would have to be cleaned by the gc?

Comment: An array of fixed size like in `int[CELLS_X][CELLS_Y][MAX_NB_BALLS]` would work but is limited by the number of balls you can have. Apps don't have unlimited memory :)

Comment: Hmm, a lot to think about :) Thank you for all the help

Answer (score 2):

Try sorting the balls by position. This may reduce the number of computations that you'd need to do, as you'll only need to compare each ball with others that are nearby — once a ball is too far away (on the axis you're sorting by, at least) then you don't need to consider any balls that are further away.

Answer (score 1):

Just a short point:
- In your second loop you can start from i+1 (I believe that that was your intention)

```
for(int j = i+1; j < size; j++){
```

If you really are searching for a data structure then you can take a look at space partitioning trees. (e.g. [kd-trees](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/K-d_tree), [Quad-trees](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quadtree), etc. From your code I am assuming a 2D space). However, you should be aware that maintaining such data structures in a dynamic environment (moving balls) might be too expensive. You should decide on the level of detail that brings you the best payoff.

Answer (score 0):

**How often do you call handleCollisions()? and how fast do these balls move?**

My guess is you must make a better match between these 2 numbers, playing with distances.

For example, if 1 ball was 20 units from closest ball and all balls have moved 2 units since last call to handleCollisions(), then it's impossible this ball had a collision, so skip it. In certain cases, maybe you'll be able to skip all balls (skip the call to handleCollisions).

Comment: Interesting idea. I currently call handleCollisions() on each frame. The speed of the balls is variable, but ranges between 0-5 pixels/ frame. I suppose I could work in some code to determine if there is no ball nearby and skip it in the next iteration. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Have you also considered not bothering to assign the current ball to a variable?
It's possible that the time you see being spent "accessing the array" is actually spent with allocating and assigning the local variable.  You can simply access the ball via indexing into the array.  I'm not sure how much of a difference it will make, but it's worth a try.